# Identify this in soil?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, houseplants, plant-health

These look exactly like white grapes and they’re in the soil.

Does anyone know what this is?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are root nodules, it is normal and healthy to develop these "bulbils". They help the fern to survive in harsh times, because the nodules store water and nutrient. Read [here](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/houseplants/boston-fern/root-nodules-on-boston-fern.htm) more about it.

Comment: Thanks for your help